# How long does it take plants to grow?

Tags: nier-replicant-1.22474487139

After completing the *Shopping List* quest, I unlocked the ability to plant seeds in my backyard. The first time I tried growing crops, I waited a few days only to return and find that my plants had all died.

How long does it take for crops to grow? Is the growth time affected by the type of seed or fertilizer used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Game Wiki](https://nierreplicant.wiki.fextralife.com/Cultivating):

> It will take approximately 24 hours before it bears fruit. This is tied to real-time but can be manipulated if the system clock is manually changed. Harvest the field. Leave it for 2 days or more and they will potentially wither. Using a fertilizer will either speed up the process or increase the outcome of the plant.

[This guide](https://www.thegamer.com/nier-replicant-guide-cultivating-plants-hybrid-flowers/) also claims the same:

> Growing plants and vegetables uses real-world time, so this isn't a quick process. Usually, it takes a whole day for something to fully grow, and another day for it to die

It seems the amount of time for each crop is the same, with the only thing changing the growth time being the speed fertilizer - and I suppose manipulating your system clock as well, but that's not an *in game* solution.  I found a few sources such as [this one](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/286768-nier-replicant-ver122474487139/79462510) claiming the speed fertilizer cuts the time in half:

> I've read that it cuts the growing time in half, but not the harvest/decay time